# Bootstrap btn-group-toggle change another group based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap button-group-toggle. Both options could be off, but only one could be on. If option1 is on, option2 should be off. If option2 is on, option1 should be off. Is it possible to do this?

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" id="option1">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="option1_on">
        <input type="radio" name="options_option1" value="on"> On
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="option1_off">
        <input type="radio" name="options_option1" value="off"> Off
    </label>
</div>


<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" id="option2">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="option2_on">
        <input type="radio" name="options_option2" value="on"> On
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="option2_off">
        <input type="radio" name="options_option2" value="off"> Off
    </label>
</div>
```

This is what I tried with javascript:

```
$(function() {
    
    $("#option1 input:radio").change(function() {
        var optionValue = $(this).val();
        if (optionValue == 'on'){
            //Option2 must be off
            $("#option2_off").button('toggle');  
        }
        
    });
    
    $("#option2 input:radio").change(function() {
        var optionValue = $(this).val();
        if (optionValue == 'on'){
            //Option1 must be off
            $("#option1_on").button('dispose');  
        }
        
    });

});
```

This does not work correctly.

## Edit1

The answer does not work visualy on bootstrap 4 [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p8q3hpao/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select siblings of clicked element and find `input` with value `off` and set its `checked` value with jquery. It will also work for more then 2 groups [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2702/)

```js
$(".btn-group-toggle input:radio").on('change', function() {
  let val = $(this).val();
  if (val == 'on') {
    var sibling = $(this)
      .parents('.btn-group-toggle')
      .siblings()
      .find('input[value="off"]')
      .prop('checked', true)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" id="option1">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="option1_on">
    <input type="radio" name="options_option1" value="on"> On
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="option1_off">
    <input type="radio" name="options_option1" value="off"> Off
  </label>
</div>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" id="option2">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="option2_on">
    <input type="radio" name="options_option2" value="on"> On
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary" id="option2_off">
    <input type="radio" name="options_option2" value="off"> Off
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great, but not visualy if you lay bootstrap4 on top. Check the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/p8q3hpao/2/

Comment: In that case you also need to toggle `active` class on label like this https://jsfiddle.net/p8q3hpao/6/

Comment: Thank you! What should I have in siblings() if I want to wrap every button-group in a div? https://jsfiddle.net/hb428bo9/1/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!